# How to get values dynamically based on parameters in Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I did Helm Chart helper file as follows:

```
{{- define "logging.log_path" -}}
{{- if and .Values.log_path (eq .Values.app_type "sales") }}
{{- join "," .Values.log_path.sales }}
{{ else if and .Values.log_path (eq .Values.app_type "inventory") }}
{{- join "," .Values.log_path.inventory }}
{{ else if and .Values.log_path (eq .Values.app_type "order") }}
{{- join "," .Values.log_path.order }}
{{ else if and .Values.log_path (eq .Values.app_type "warehouse") }}
{{- join "," .Values.log_path.warehouse }}
{{ else }}
{{- join "," .Values.log_path.sales }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

The problem is whenever it's required to add new `app_type`, I need to add `app_type` in that file manually. I think it's difficult to maintain and time consuming either.

Is there anyway that I could do like that `.Values.log_path[".Values.app_type"]` or any solution similar to that one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm includes a [dictionary helper](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dictionaries-and-dict-functions) [`get`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#get)

`get $myDict "key1"`

```
{{ define "logging.log_path" }}
{{- $path := get .Values.log_path .Values.app_type | default .Values.log_path.sales -}}
{{- join "," $path -}}
{{ end }}
```